# .net custom claims identity authentication: User role is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, roles, claims-based-identity

I'm working in a .Net api which uses jwt token auth, and everything's working fine regarding token generation/validation, but my problem arises when getting user role from token to do role validation in some endpoints.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

#region swagger
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
  option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
  option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
  {
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "Please enter a valid token",
    Name = "Authorization",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = "Bearer"
  });
  option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
#endregion

#region jwt data
var validIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"];
var validAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"];
var issuerSigningKey = builder.Configuration["JWT:IssuerSigningKey"];
#endregion

if (validIssuer != null && validAudience != null && issuerSigningKey != null)
{
  #region jwt
  builder.Services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  //.AddAuthentication(options =>
  //{
  //    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  //})
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
      ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
      ValidAudience = validAudience,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
              Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(issuerSigningKey)
          ),
    };
  });
  #endregion

  #region DbContext
  var connectionString = Util.getAppSettingsValue("ConnectionStrings:SurveyConnection");
  if (connectionString == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("SQL connection string is not set in appsettings.json!");
  }
  builder.Services.AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
  });
  #endregion

  #region neo4j data
  var neo4jServer = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:server"];
  var neo4jUser = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:user"];
  var neo4jPwd = builder.Configuration["Neo4J:pwd"];
  #endregion

  if (neo4jServer != null && neo4jUser != null && neo4jPwd != null)
  {
    #region neo4j
    var client = new BoltGraphClient(new Uri(neo4jServer), neo4jUser, neo4jPwd);
    client.ConnectAsync();
    #endregion

    #region services

    #region repository
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISurveysRepository, SurveysRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBlocksRepository, BlocksRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IQuestionsRepository, QuestionsRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOptionsRepository, OptionsRepository>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAnswersRepository, AnswersRepository>();
    #endregion

    #region domain
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISurveysApplication, SurveysApplication>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBlocksApplication, BlocksApplication>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IQuestionsApplication, QuestionsApplication>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOptionsApplication, OptionsApplication>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAnswersApplication, AnswersApplication>();
    #endregion

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthService>();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGraphClient>(client);

    builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
    builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenService, TokenService>();
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    #endregion

    #region users
    builder.Services
            .AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
              options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
              options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
              options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
              options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
              options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
              options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
              options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            }).AddRoles<ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<UsersDbContext>();
    #endregion

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    //{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    //}

    #region swagger default page in release mode
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
      {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Surveys Web API");
        options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
      });
      app.UseHsts();
    }
    #endregion

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception("Neo4J is not configured!");
  }
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("JWT is not configured!");
}
```

CreateUser:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync(UserRequest user)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  //TODO: Validate required fields

  var identityUser = new ApplicationUser
  {
    UserName = user.Username,
    Email = user.Email,
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName
  };
  var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(
      identityUser,
      user.Passwd
  );
  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
    string[] roles = { "Administrator" };
    await AddRolesAsync(identityUser, roles);
    return Created($"{Request.GetHost()}/ftq/user/{identityUser.Id}", null);
  }
  foreach (var error in result.Errors)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError(error.Code, error.Description);
  }
  return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

AddRoles:

```
private async Task<IdentityResult> AddRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user, string[] rolesToAdd)
{
  //actualizo el rol
  var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
  var removeRoleResult = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
  if (!removeRoleResult.Succeeded)
    return removeRoleResult;

  //agrego los nuevos roles
  var addedRol = new IdentityResult();
  foreach (var rol in rolesToAdd)
  {
    addedRol = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, rol);
    if (!addedRol.Succeeded)
      return removeRoleResult;
  }
  return addedRol;
}
```

ApplicationRole:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
  public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
  [Required]
  [MaxLength(256)]
  [Display(Name = "First Name")]
  public string? FirstName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MaxLength(256)]
  [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
  public string? LastName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Display(Name = "Status")]
  public bool Status { get; set; } = true;

  //propiedad con relacion a tabla de roles de usuarios
  public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUserRole:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
  //propiedad con relacion a tabla de usuarios
  public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

  //propiedad con relacion a tabla de roles
  public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

UsersDbContext:

```
public class UsersDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser
                                    , ApplicationRole
                                    , Guid
                                    , IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
                                    , ApplicationUserRole
                                    , IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
                                    , IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>
                                    , IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
{
  public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext> context) : base(context)
  {
  }

  public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<ApplicationRole> AppRoles { get; set; }
  public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> AppUserRoles { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable(name: "User");
      //configuro relacion entre usuario y rol
      entity.HasMany(u => u.UserRoles)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    });
    builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
    });
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
      entity.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

      entity.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
          .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
          .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
          .IsRequired();

      entity.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
          .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
          .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
          .IsRequired();
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable("UserClaims")
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable("UserLogins")
            .HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
    });
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>(entity =>
    {
      entity.ToTable("UserTokens")
            .HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    });
  }
}
```

GetCurrentUser:

```
public User? GetCurrentUser(HttpContext httpContext)
{
  var identity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
  if (identity != null)
  {
    var userClaims = identity.Claims;
    if (userClaims != null)
    {
      var username = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
      var email = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
      var role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;

      if (username != null && email != null && role != null) {
        return new User
        {
          Username = username,
          Email = email,
          Role = role
        };
      }
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Here in GetCurrentUser role is always null.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the template to create the application and it uses the `AddDefaultIdentity` function to add the identity role. Here is the code of the Model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

 

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
    }

 

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the code of DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

I directly operated the database table and added the role of user, you can see from the screenshot:
[image]

And I can see in the your given code, you are using the `AddIdentityCore` function. But if I tried to use your code, there was an error message:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser]'
> has been registered.

So I checked some information and here is my changed codes:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Besides that, I change the code in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` to

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

I find out that if I use `AddIdentityCore` and `AddDefaultIdentity` at the same time, the error message will not show up and here is my test result which you can get the current user's role via httpcontext:
[image]